# Can AWS SQS be Used in a Django Project with django-celery-results Backend?

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs, django-celery

Pre-warning: there is A LOT I don't understand

**My Requirement**

I need to be able to get the result of a celery task. I need the status to change to `'SUCCESS'` when completed successfully.

For example:

I need to be able to get the result of `x + y` after executing `add.delay(1,2)` on the task below.

myapp/tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from time import sleep

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    sleep(10)
    return x + y
```

## Is AWS SQS the right tool for my needs?

I read Celery's [Using Amazon SQS](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html) and understand at the bottom it says this about the results.

> **Results**
>
> Multiple products in the Amazon Web Services family could be
> a good candidate to store or publish results with, but there’s no such
> result backend included at this point.

## Question:

### Does this mean [django-celery-results](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-results/) can't be used with AWS SQS?

### More Context Below

---

What I am doing executionally?

1. I look at my AWS queue (shows messages available as 3)
2. In my local terminal, I do `celery -A ebdjango worker --loglevel=INFO` (see celery output below)
3. In my PyCharm Python console connected to my Django project, I do `r = add.delay(1,2)`
4. `r` is an `AsyncResult` object:

```
>>> r = add.delay(1,2)
>>> r
<AsyncResult: b69c4287-5c82-4873-aa8c-227547511233>
```

5. In AWS, my "Messages available" went from 3 to 4
6. Locally, in my terminal, nothing happened (I expect SQS to send the message back to me locally? Is this wrong?)
7. I inspect `r` and see this:

```
    >>> r.id
    'b69c4287-5c82-4873-aa8c-227547511233'
    >>> r.status
    'PENDING'
    >>> r.result
    >>> type(r.result)
    <class 'NoneType'>
```

ebdjango/settings.py

```
...
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"

CELERY_BROKER_URL = "sqs://"
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'us-west-2',
    'visibility_timeout': 3600,
    'predefined_queues': {
        'eb-celery-queue': {
            'url': 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/12345678910/eb-celery-queue',
            'access_key_id': AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            'secret_access_key': AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        }
    }
}

CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL = False
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'eb-celery-queue'
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY = 1
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_CONTENT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db' <-- Note: I have django-celery-results installed and set
```

Celery output at start:

```
(eb-virt) C:\Users\Jarad\Documents\PyCharm\DEVOPS\ebdjango>celery -A ebdjango worker --loglevel=INFO
[2021-08-27 14:35:31,914: WARNING/MainProcess] No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'None'

 -------------- celery@Inspiron v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 2021-08-27 14:35:31
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         ebdjango:0x1d64e4d4630
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqs://localhost//
- ** ---------- .> results:
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> eb-celery-queue  exchange=eb-celery-queue(direct) key=eb-celery-queue


[tasks]
  . ebdjango.celery.debug_task
  . homepage.tasks.add
  . homepage.tasks.count_widgets
  . homepage.tasks.cu
  . homepage.tasks.mul
  . homepage.tasks.rename_widget
  . homepage.tasks.xsum

[2021-08-27 14:35:31,981: WARNING/MainProcess] No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'None'
[2021-08-27 14:35:31,981: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqs://localhost//
[2021-08-27 14:35:32,306: WARNING/MainProcess] ...
[2021-08-27 14:35:32,307: INFO/MainProcess] celery@Inspiron ready.
```

I do notice that 1) `results:`  section shows empty (like it's not defined) and 2) the `task events` are OFF which might be because task events aren't supported for SQS, but I don't know for certain. It seems I can set `CELERY_SEND_EVENTS` and it has no effect on `task events` output here.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to show all the task data in the TaskResults entry you need to add this to your 'settings.py'

```
CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED = True
```